# How to put the application in the background and return to put in the foreground (watchOS and iOS)?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I am making an application for watchOS which aims to receive some notifications, and the device which sends these notifications is the iPhone.

I have managed to make the communication between the Apple Watch and the iPhone and the iPhone already sends messages to the Apple Watch and the Apple Watch also already sends messages to the iPhone. I did not use the `WatchNotification` tool.

What's happening is the following, when I run the application, it automatically opens in the Apple Watch, and what I want is that the application stays running at the background. When I press a button in the iPhone, a text is sent to the Apple Watch, and only then (when the Apple Watch receives the text) the application opens normally.

I'll appreciate any help.

**iPhone Code**

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController,WCSessionDelegate {

var iphoneNotification = "Deseja renovar o seu seguro automovel?"
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
@IBOutlet weak var lblNotification: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    initSession()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func ActionSentNotification(sender: AnyObject) {
    let msg = ["NotificationSentforIphone" : iphoneNotification]

    session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: {(replay) -> Void in }) { (error) -> Void in



    }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])

{

    let msg = message["NotificationSentforWatch"] as! String
    lblNotification.text = "\(msg)"


}

func initSession()

{

    session.delegate = self

    session.activateSession()




}
}
```

**Watch Code**

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController,WCSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet var Notification: WKInterfaceLabel!
var watchNotification = "ok"
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
//@IBOutlet var lblNotification: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    initSession()
    super.willActivate()
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])

{

    let msg = message["NotificationSentforIphone"] as! String
    Notification.setText("\(msg)")
    //lblNotification.setText("Notification:\(msg)")

}
@IBAction func ActionSentNotificationforIphone()
{
    let msg = ["NotificationSentforWatch" : watchNotification]

    session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: {(replay) -> Void in }) { (error) -> Void in



    }

}
override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}

func initSession()

{

    session.delegate=self

    session.activateSession()



}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to programatically open an Apple Watch app, nor to 'automatically' open one. The only way for an Apple Watch app to launch is through direct user action (which may include tapping on a notification or glance).

It sounds like you may be observing what happens in the *simulator*, when you build your application's WatchKit Extension. This is akin to a user launching the app. If you want to be able to test the usual use of the WatchKit App, leave the WatchOS simulator running, and build the iPhone target. You can then interact with the iPhone app, plus manually launch the WatchKit app during the iPhone app lifecycle at any point you choose.